# How do I convert .bin code property graph to json?

Tags: machine-learning, graph, abstract-syntax-tree, control-flow-graph, joern

How can I convert a code property `graph(cpg)` obtained from joern (https://joern.io/) from *.bin* format to *.json* format for feeding it to a graph machine learning library for classification.

**Note:** CPG = AST + Control Flow Graph + Program Dependency Graph

**Task:** Machine Learning on Source Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scala script '[graph-for-funcs.sc](https://github.com/ShiftLeftSecurity/joern/blob/master/joern-cli/src/main/resources/scripts/graph/graph-for-funcs.sc)' which is included in the joern scripts directory. However you need to redirect the output in order to store it in file (since the output goes to stdout by default).
I made a custom script to do so.